# Add an inherited subview to my view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, inheritance, view

I currently working on a project with a lot of similitude with a lot of view.
I would know if there is a way to send a subview from a root class to an inherited class.

Here is my RootViewController :

```
@class CustomView;
@interface RootViewController : UIViewController {
       IBOutlet CustomView  *_aCustomView;
}
@end

@implementation RootViewController
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipRecognizer;

    // swipe left management
    swipRecognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self 
                                                               action:@selector(handleSwipeFrom:)];
    swipRecognizer.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;
    swipRecognizer.numberOfTouchesRequired = 2;
    swipRecognizer.delegate = self;
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:swipRecognizer];
    [swipRecognizer release];
}

- (void)handleSwipeFrom:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    NSLog(@"swip detected");
    [self.view addSubview:_aCustomView];
}
```

The HomeViewController:

```
@interface HomeViewController : RootViewController {
}
@end
```

I would create some ViewController wich inherit from my `RootViewController` like this `HomeViewController` in order to save line code. When I am in my `HomeViewController`, I detect well my swipe but I didn't yet manage to add my custom `subView` (coming from my RootViewController) to my HomeViewController.

Thx a lot.
Regards,
kl94

Comment: similitude with what?  Your question is unclear. Could you let us know what you have tried and how it did not work? What do you mean 'send' a subview from a root class to an inherited class?

Comment: I agree, my question wasn't clear. Sorry for that... I've edited my post with the hope you'll understand what I need.

Answer (score 0):

You should add a constructor method to your custom view which initialize your view with an object from your model.

For example :

I your RootViewController you have a Customer object and a CustomerView displaying informations about this customer.

In CustomerView you should create a method :

```
-(id) initWithFrame:(CGRect) frame customer:(Customer) customer;
```

If you need to display the same CustomerView in your HomeViewController, just add a Customer object as a property of your HomeViewController and in the viewDidLoad just init a CustomerView with :

```
CustomerView *customerView = [[CustomerView alloc] iniFrame:CGRectMake(...) customer:currentCustomer;
[self.view addSubView:customerView];
[customerView release];
```

Hope this helps,
Vincent.

Comment: It's a good idea in order to manage my custom class . And you helped me to find my answer. It was actually a question about initalization.

Answer (score 0):

Well I find a solution. My problem was about I attempted to add an IBOutlet object not initialized Hope I'll don't regret it later :

In my HomeViewController i've override the method `initWithNibName:bundle:` :

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization.
    }
    return self;
}
```

And my RootViewController :

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
    self = [super initWithNibName:@"RootViewController" bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization.
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: If initialisation is your issue you can hook viewDidLoad in your controller.

Comment: yes, now I know. But for the moment I use initWithNibName:bundle: in order to init some IB object. I think it's the better way. Thx anyway